# QGIS - HtmlWidget with <iframe> from localhost

Tags: qgis, qgis-widget

I'm using `QGIS 3.28.4` and want to build an `HTML Widget` to display a web page. I can display `<iframe>` elements from web, but I want to try it from a `localhost` address, is it possible ?

- Exemple with an `<iframe>` from web

[image: osm]

```
<iframe width="300" height="200" src="https://www.openstreetmap.org/export/embed.html?bbox=-0.004017949104309083%2C51.47612752641776%2C0.00030577182769775396%2C51.478569861898606&layer=mapnik"></iframe>
```

- Same syntax with `localhost` but nothing display

[image: localhost]

```
<iframe width="300" height="400" src="http://localhost:8008/admin/"></iframe>
```

Edit:
In a regular browser I have an error message: `localhost refused to connect`

[image: browser_error]

Comment: Can you see your `iframe` in a regular browser?

Comment: I edit my post with a screenshot. I have an error message: `localhost refused to connect`

Comment: Check this : https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/localhost-refused-to-connect-error